# Hacking Atom editor - how to throw atom-style exception from custom plugin?

Tags: javascript, exception, plugins, atom-editor

I'm developing a plugin for a GitHub [**Atom**](https://atom.io/) editor, and I need to throw an Exception in case of plugin's misconfiguration (or internal error).

I want them to appear in the top right corner, as standard Atom error widget, but I can't find any clue about it in the Web.

Doing simple `throw Error('...');` is not handled by the editor, and produces only console output.

Maybe someone did this?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: What's up with the downvote? Sublime-only lovers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The api call to do this is:

```
atom.notifications.addError('string to display in error message')
```

if you are developing the plugin in node.js.

If you are using Coffeescript, then I would guess it would be the same but with a syntax change for node.js versus Coffeescript.

Comment: Thank you, virtuous stranger. That's exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: @KidBinary To be honest, I only know this because it is legacy code in a linter package I maintain for the atom-linter org. Glad it helped you though.

Comment: It worth mentioning in the official documentation, that's for sure. But, thanks to you, now community can quickly google for it : )